# Unable to Execute testng.xml file through command prompt window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Sorry for the repetitive post but I'm unable to resolve this issue. Have tried to troubleshoot this issue, but most of the questions and posts are also following the same commands or processes that I have followed to execute the testng.xml file in the command prompt window. Have followed different methods too, But I can't make this issue go away, please kindly provide your insights. I have been trying to execute my testng.xml file in command prompt window, at the first time I wrote a simple SysOut statement and it executed perfectly fine and then I have added simple java code given below:

```
package com.vijay.jenkins;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Demo {

@Test
public void j()  
{
    System.out.println("Hi bindu ");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
   "C:\\Users\\viju4\\Desktop\\selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
     //Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/");

    System.out.println("The title of the page is "+driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

i have followed the below commands to execute my testng.xml file in the cmd line:

```
1.cd F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG
java -cp F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\lib\*;F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\bin 
org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
2.cd F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG
set classpath=F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\bin;
set classpath=F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\lib\*;
java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

when I execute the simple test case using these commands worked fine but when I tried to execute the selenium code given above it is throwing below error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzArc.png)

Thanks in advance,
Bindu.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below commands will work

```
java -cp F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\lib\*;F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\bin org.testng.TestNG F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\testng.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Balakrishnan, Have executed the commands you have specified earlier. But it is showing failures 1 in the output. But it is working fine in the eclipse IDE without throwing any errors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Balakrishnan, Have executed the commands you have specified earlier. But it is showing failures 1 in the output. But it is working fine in the Eclipse IDE without throwing any errors. It is executing the SysOut statement only, the remaining code is not executing I guess please help me. command window  msg:                    
Hi bindu

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: You can follow the steps in the site http://automationtesting.in/running-testng-xml-using-command-prompt/

Comment: Have tried the process given in that post, but still getting the same error. I have used ANT build tool to execute the .xml file through command prompt, and it has executed perfectly fine without throwing any error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks bro @balakrishnan, finally after spending whole day, I found the answer. Those of you still unable to find the  answer, follow the link of his blog he has explained it very well.
Here I am attaching the link again, 
http://automationtesting.in/running-testng-xml-using-command-prompt/

If still you guys have problem, comment down the issue, I will be happy to help.